# Keyboard switching doesn't work in xfce4 in any sense

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, xfce, input-method

After playing with installing / uninstalling of KDE/GNOME/Mate I got a situation, where I can't switch keyboards in `Xfce4` at all.

Applet is configured normally

[image]

and Keyboard layouts panel is showing

[image]

Unfortunately, if I press specified shortcut (`Ctrl-Shift`) nothing happens (neither indicator changes, nor input changes). Also if I press indicator by mouse, it changes, but input doesn't change.

What components can be lost here? What components of other desktops can interfere here? How to debug a situation?

Comment: What Linux distro do you use?

Comment: @Krackout Ubuntu 18 LTS

Comment: I have the same issue on Mint 20, not sure what is going on with XFCE

Answer (score 6):

Actually, for me worked just enabling `Use system defaults` and then disabling it again in the xfce4 Settings -> Keyboard (upper left tick box on the screen shot you posted). No any additional package installations needed. Just click the switch couple of times and layout switching starts working.

Comment: Year 2024, Debian 12, XFCE4 and this hacky solution does the job.

Answer (score 2):

You can also edit /etc/default/keyboard manually, here's an example:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us,de,fr,ua,ru"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle"

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

XKBMODEL is a keyboard model variable (look at a /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst (plain text) or /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.xml (XML) for a full list);

XKBLAYOUT variable contains a list of used layouts;

"grp:alt_shift_toggle" sets a layout switching key combination (+).

To apply new settings, restarting the keyboard-setup service should suffice, otherwise you can try to restart kernel input system via udev:

#service keyboard-setup restart

#udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=input --action=change

**How to set keyboard layout in initramfs**

The appropriate section of /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf needs to be changed to have a localized keyboard layout at boot time:

```
#
# KEYMAP: [ y | n ]
#
# Load a keymap during the initramfs stage.
#

KEYMAP=y
```

Apply changes:

#update-initramfs -u

https://wiki.debian.org/Keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct solution but a workabout with the same result. In Debian and derivatives like Ubuntu, you can set the keyboard layout, shortcut to switch layouts, etc using this command:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`

After setting the keyboard there, you should check `use system defaults` on the xfce4 Settings -> Keyboard (upper left tick box on the screen shot you posted). Then I believe you'll be able to switch layouts and it should also be displayed correctly on your panel.

Added bonus, setting keyboard this way you can have multiple layouts and switching on console-framebuffer also, not only X.

---

It's a bit odd that `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` does not give you any interactive menu to choose keyboards. I've just tested it in an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS VM and it works fine.

Nevertheless, I'm sending you the produced `/etc/default/keyboard` file. I used the same settings as the ones on your screenshot. Copy-paste in your `/etc/default/keyboard` file, removing everything else. Set `use system defaults`, reboot your computer and it should work.

`/etc/default/keyboard`

```
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us,ru"
XKBVARIANT=",typewriter"
XKBOPTIONS="grp:ctrl_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Comment: Didn't help. If I set `use system defaults` then the layout controls turn grayed and I can't specify layouts anymore. What are system defaults and how to control layouts in this case?

Comment: System defaults are set using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` or by manually editing `/etc/default/keyboard` file. Did you run the reconfigure first, before checking to use system defaults?

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` just does some output into console, it doesn't ask me, which layouts to use and by which key to switch between them

Comment: @Dims I added the configuration file `/etc/default/keyboard` produced by `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` in my answer. Try this if you like.

Comment: Ya, I have similar file, but everything doesn't work anyway.

Comment: for me just clicking the `use system defaults` couple of times fixed layout switching, just enable it and then disable again.

Answer (score 0):

The above method worked for me, but only if I selected remove the language options from the configuration file, and unchecked system defaults after dpkg-reconfigure.